# Unsupported HTTP response code 429

Tags: apache-httpd

I am using `Apache 2.2`. In that I want to send back error code 429 in case of any page called on my server. But I am getting this error `"Unsupported HTTP response code 429"` when I am restarting my Apache server.
In httpd.conf below changes I have done:

```
ErrorDocument 429 "Too Many Requests"
```

Why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like apache 2.2 does not have 4xx status codes above 
*426 Upgrade Required* (except for *449 Retry With*). See
[this list](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-status-code-headers-errordocument.html) culled from the sources.

The dynamically created [list for 2.4.4](http://www.askapache.com/net/http-status-codes.html) does include 429.

Comment: Is there evidence from where we can prove that 429 is not supported in apache 2.2 and from where apache send http error codes i mean where the setup is defined for that

Comment: [this](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/branches/2.2.x/modules/http/http_protocol.c) is the svn repository for 2.2 source file `http_protocol.c` in which you can see all the supported codes, and 429 is not in there.  [this](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-cvs/201207.mbox/%3C20120720143209.59DFB23889DA@eris.apache.org%3E) is the patch where it was added to the 2.4 version of apache on 20 Jul 2012.

Answer (score 2):

While [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html) states that

> Customized error responses can be defined for any HTTP status code designated as an error condition - that is, any 4xx or 5xx status.

…the reality is that it only allows styling errors generated by httpd itself. Thus only errors known to httpd can be set as the target code for [ErrorDocument](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument) statement.

TL;DR: Documentation is lying to you.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you linked to the documentation you are quoting and/or a source for your “reality” conclusion.  … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it more complete.